# Chromebook Ubuntu deleted?

Tags: chromebook

I was running ubuntu 14.04 dual boot on my chromebook just fine.  But when my cousins used my computer they pressed `SPACE` at the `OS Verification is off press space enable` on the bootup screen and I can't get into Ubuntu now.

Did I loose everything? Is it gone? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me, and to make matters that much more upsetting, the person who deleted my installation, my girlfriend, was present for the installation and said she understood what you must do at each prompt.  After wiping out my installation, she then said she only did what the computer told her to do.

We now have a strict rule she is not to use my Chromebook, AT ALL.  An exception will be made if or when I get done printing labels spelling out exactly what to do at each prompt.  The first label will read "STOP!  Do not do what the computer tells you!"

So, just to be clear, your installation is COMPLETELY GONE.  There is no getting it back.  Please address your complaints to Google for posting instructions on each screen of developer mode which instruct no-nothing-novices to wipe out custom installations.

Comment: Boy that is one good reason for me *NOT* to buy one of those things.

Comment: @psusi, not necessarily.  The method used to install ubuntu ALONGSIDE chrome in "developer mode" is not nearly the same thing as actually installing "chrubuntu" in place of the chrome OS.  Developer mode installations are rather temporary in so much as that there is absolutely no means short of a chastity belt and a padlock that you can keep people from resetting your installation.

Comment: Ahh, that is good to know; I thought their boot loader was locked in and you couldn't get rid of that.

Comment: @psusi, I should be clear that I've not actually tried installing chrubuntu, and for all I know there is another major inconvenience there as well that I simply haven't experienced.  However as far as installations in developer mode, the second time around I learned to download portions into an external, say "non-volatile" folder so that I could more easily reconstitute the installation if it became deleted again which by then I realized was somewhat likely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have one, but everything I just read said that pressing space there basically factory resets everything. I believe you will need to reset up developer mode and start again, sorry.

Comment: when I check my hardrive space at "chrome://quota-internals/" it shows 1.5gb free and my harddrive is 4gb so i feel like it has to be here somewhere.

Comment: From what I read and what others are saying, it's gone. Even if it is still there, the only way to get out to work again is to enable developer mode again, and from my understanding, that also wipes things out.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry but your Ubuntu is completely gone you need to download it again and start from scratch. So sudo sh -e Downloads/crouton -t unity or change unity to kde4 of fxe

Answer (score 0):

Yes pressing the spacebar will completely wipe the internal drive.

One solution is to leave Chrome OS as is and install Ubuntu on a USB 3.0 drive so that you have the best of both operating systems. If someone does press space, your Ubuntu install will not be affected.

I've posted a video and written guide outlining the whole procedure for [dual booting Linux and Chrome OS on a Chromebook](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/howto/dual-boot-chrome-os-and-linux).